# Unexpected behaviour of TeX condition in \draw macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, tikz-node

Let's consider code below

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}     
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
         \draw (\i,0)  
         \ifnum\i=2 node [below, black] {$a$}\fi 
         to node [pos=1.15, above, black, sloped] {$x = const$}({\i+1},5);
     }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I applied a condition `\ifnum ... \fi` for mark some node below the first coordinate of the drawing line. On the second `node` which is near the second coordinate of line there is no condition.

But if I apply some condition on the second `node`, say

```
\ifnum\i=3 node [pos=1.15, above, black, sloped] {$x = const$}\fi
```

I get an error

```
! Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected.
```

Here is an example of code with such an error.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
         \draw (\i,0)  
         \ifnum\i=2 node [below, black] {$a$}\fi 
         to \ifnum\i=3 node [pos=1.15, above, black, sloped] {$x = const$}\else\relax\fi {$x = const$} ({\i+1},5);
     }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why does the second condition cause an error, in spite of the fact that the logic of its application is the same as for the first node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `to`, the parser is specifically set to look out for a coordinate or a node name literally. That's why it is tripping.

In the first example it found a coordinate and now parsing the context (is it a `--`, is it a `to` etc.) and hence will expand until it finds something useful.

Note that TikZ parser works character by character. If it sees `c`it checks if it is `controls` or `coordinate` and so on by branching. So it is not executing blocks and trying to make meaning out of them.

Comment: What to do to avoid the error?

Comment: @sergiokapone move if before the to

Comment: @percusse I think the solution should be in the answer, not a comment.